# How do i run php code in fan page?

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way i could run php code in facebook fan page. Basically i want to show the producsts from this site:

http://ohlalashopping.co.uk/

on one of the tabs of fan page. I would love to see any possible solutions to achieve just that.

**Edit:**

Based on the answers provided, i just wanted to ask one more thing:

How do i add the iframe app to the fan page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a Facebook application that displays products from your website, and then install that application to a tab on your fan page.

When an application is installed in a tab, Facebook will query the url you've specified in your application settings. This is different from the regular way of accessing applications in that users don't need to install the application to use it.

Comment: what if i make iframe app (which will basically get data from http://ohlalashopping.co.uk/ through iframe's src attribute) and show that in fab page, is this possible?

Comment: Yes - in fact, that's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: can u please tell me how do i add iframe app that i will create into fan page?

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute PHP on Facebook.  You can write a [Facebook App](http://developers.facebook.com/) or widget which accesses data from your php application.   There is also a [PHP Client API for Facebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP) which can be used to tie together Facebook and your PHP web application.

Comment: what if i make iframe app (which will basically get data from http://ohlalashopping.co.uk/ through iframe's src attribute) and show that in fab page, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

it is also possible you can make iframe application